# Outputting data with keeping spaces in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What should I change in the formula to output the numbers in the column **with** spaces, if they are in the "data" column? At the same time, make sure to save the condition, according to which the data is output according to cell E2 (twopoints).

Now there is a formula (in the yellow cell), which by condition pulls the necessary numbers from the cells and outputs them to the column **without** spaces. File link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SgimsVnIE_-8SifLWK__3Okjq2mkSSSju-cCISDoJ7Q/edit#gid=125682155

```
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(MAP(E2;LAMBDA(z;FILTER(TOCOL(A3:C;3);REGEXMATCH(TOCOL(A3:C;3);"(?i)"&z))));)=TRUE;REGEXEXTRACT(MAP(E2;LAMBDA(z;FILTER(TOCOL(A3:C;3);REGEXMATCH(TOCOL(A3:C;3);"(?i)"&z))));"([0-9]+):");));COUNTA(A3:A);1)
```

Comment: What is logic to have empty cells to your desired output column although they have data in C column?

Comment: Empty - only for cells that contains "twopoints" inside themselves. Not all dataset from B,C columns with spaces I needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try:

```
=byrow(B3:C;lambda(Σ;if(counta(Σ)=0;;ifna(--regexextract(torow(index(if(regexmatch(Σ;E2);Σ;));1);"(\d+):")))))
```

[image]